# Break out from a switch with a delay: setTimeout + break = syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, break

I'm trying to make some animation relying on the CSS transitions, adding and removing classes: (now some code, then some further explanation)

```
/*variables are defined outside this function*/
function effect() {
    switch(activeWall.attr("animation-order")) {
        case "incremental":
            if(!j) { /*if first box*/
                boxes.eq(j).addClass("hovered");
                ++j;
                break;
            };

            if (j == defaultOrder.lenght) { /*if last box*/
                boxes.eq(j).removeClass("hovered");
                setTimeout(break, 1000); /*syntax error*/
            };

            /*any other*/
            boxes.eq(j).addClass("hovered");
            boxes.eq(j-1).removeClass("hovered");
            ++j;
            break;

        default:
            if(!i) { /*if first box*/
                boxes.eq(defaultOrder[i]).addClass("hovered");
                ++i;
                break;
            };

            if (i == defaultOrder.lenght) { /*if last box*/
                boxes.eq(defaultOrder[i]).removeClass("hovered");
                setTimeout(break, 1000); /*syntax error*/
            };

            /*any other*/
            boxes.eq(defaultOrder[i]).addClass("hovered");
            boxes.eq(defaultOrder[i-1]).removeClass("hovered");
            ++i;
            break;
    };
};
```

The transition in `hovered` class for the user to see it in case of the last box, before something else happening, I need to wait before exiting the `switch` with a `break`. Putting a delay like this `boxes.eq(i).removeClass("hovered").delay(n)` after removing the class would be ineffective because the next jQuery animations are applied on others elements.
I thought putting the `break` with a `setTimeout` would do, but I get a syntax error.

So, how I can pause the flow of the script for the time necessary to the transition to be effective? Am I using `setTimeout` badly?

Comment: you can use `delay(1000)` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: @Rajven You've to rethink the whole logic. You can't delay the `break` of `switch` using any kind of delay JS offers (there's no `sleep` in JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `setTimeout()` to call `break`.

Try the following change:

*notice the spelling of `length` and that normally you should compare to `length - 1` to get the index of last element*

```
if (j == (defaultOrder.length-1)) { /*if last box*/
  setTimeout((function() {
    var j_ = j; //keep j during timeout
    return function() {
      boxes.eq(j_).removeClass("hovered");
    };
  })(), 1000);
  break;
}
```

The modification for `default` case is accordingly:

```
if (i == (defaultOrder.length-1)) { /*if last box*/
  setTimeout((function() {
    var i_ = i; //keep i during timeout
    return function() {
      boxes.eq(defaultOrder[i_]).removeClass("hovered");
    };
  })(), 1000);
  break;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the length advice, I'm still a beginner.

One explanation: why `i` and `j` are not in the scope of the function inside `setTimeout`?

Comment: You're welcome! Please notice my edit, I used `i` instead of `i_` in the previous version.

Comment: Sorry, still I don't understand why I have to keep the value of `i` e `j` during the timeout.